# Magento Observer method not editable

Tags: php, magento, events

I have made an Observer which reacts to a certain event. The Observer does perform the correct method, but as soon as i make changes to the code, Magento doesnt seem to pick up these changes.

I guessed it had something to do with the chache or index management, but the cache is disabled and reindexing doesnt help either.

```
class Custom_ShippingFilter_Model_Observer{

    public function salesQuoteCollectTotalsBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
         var_dump(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl());
    }
}
```

Inside the var dump used to sit `$observer` and this output keeps showing, whether i change the code or not.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that i had to run the compiler to update Magento to use the new code defined in the observer.

I used the following command:

`php -f shell/compiler.php compile`

Now everything works again.